# Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded and integrable, Show that $\exists\,\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}|f'| = |f'(\xi)|\,(b - a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded and Riemann-integrable, if $f'$ exists, which is bounded and integrable on $[a,b]$. Show that $\exists\,\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}|f'| = |f'(\xi)|\,(b - a)$

One can quickly realize the similarity between the required result and the Mean Value Theorem for definite integrals. So I want to prove it in a similar manner.

My attempt:

$min|f'|*(b-a) \le \int_{a}^{b}|f'| \le max|f'|*(b-a)$

$min|f'|\le{1\over b-a}\int_{a}^{b}|f'|\le max|f'|$

Now, **IF** $|f'|$ is continuous, then we can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to draw the conclusion that there must exist such a $\xi$.

However, integrability doesn't entail continuity. So what should I do?

Comment: The first sentence needs to be restated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
Recall than $f'$, and hence also $|f'|$, satisfies the intermediate value property (i.e., if $|f'|$ attains in an interval two different values $c < d$, then on the same interval it attains all the values $[c,d]$).

Your comparison argument shows that
$$
(b-a) \inf |f'| \leq \int_a^b |f'| \leq (b-a) \sup |f'|.
$$
Once you have considered the case $|f'|$ constant (and so $f'$ constant), the claim in the non-constant case should not be difficult to be proved.

Comment: Thank you very much! Darboux's Theorem proves that the derivatives of differentiable functions must satisfy the intermediate value property, that is the key point here!